# React TinyMCE - Data Not Binding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce, react-component, react-state-management

I created a `textarea` React component with an option to use Tiny MCE, which Im implementing using the `react-tinymce` component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TinyMCE from "react-tinymce";

class Textarea extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: {
        body: ""
      }
    };
  }

  // ..a few methods not relevant to this question..

  handleFieldChange(e) {
    const data = { ...this.state.data };
    data[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ data });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.showLabel ? (
          <label htmlFor={this.props.id}>{this.props.label}</label>
        ) : null}

        {!this.props.mce ? (
          <textarea
            className={`form-control ${this.state.error ? "error" : ""}`}
            id={this.props.id}
            type={this.props.type}
            name={this.props.name}
            value={this.props.value}
            placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
            onChange={this.handleFieldChange}
          />
        ) : (
          <TinyMCE
            name={this.props.name}
            content={this.props.value}
            config={{
              plugins: "autolink link image lists print preview code",
              toolbar:
                "undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | code",
              height: 300,
              branding: false,
              statusbar: false,
              menubar: false
            }}
            onChange={this.handleFieldChange}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Textarea;
```

I would basically use the component like this:

```
<Textarea 
  name="body" 
  label="Body"
  showLabel={true}
  placeholder="body"
  value={data.body} 
  mce={true}
/>
```

So basically if the `mce` prop is set to `true` you get the TinyMCE component.

But while the regular `textarea` version binds whatever you type into  `state.data.body`, the TinyMCE version does not.

```
// after typing into TinyMCE and submitting
console.log(this.state.data.body); // empty string
```

**please note this `Textarea` component is used as part of a form component with an onSubmit method.**

Answer (score 0):

Edited based on comment:

So here's a really basic example of data binding Tiny in React.  It uses the 'official' TinyMCE component. It looks fairly similar to yours, except using the [onEditorChange event](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-react#using-as-a-controlled-component) in order to treat the editor as a controlled component.

Now as you type, you'll see state changing in the console and your data is bound and you can get it out of state however works best for your app. Your ternary should not impact that.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Editor} from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: ''
    };
}

  handleEditorChange = (content) => {
    this.setState({ text: content });;
  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.state.text);
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <Editor
        apiKey = 'KEY'
        value={this.state.text}
        onEditorChange={this.handleEditorChange}
        init={{
            theme: 'modern',
            width: '75%',
            height: '250px',
            plugins: 'table colorpicker spellchecker powerpaste hr link media image textcolor print noneditable  lists',
            toolbar:  'styleselect | bold italic underline forecolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | outdent indent | globalImagesButton link ',
            powerpaste_allow_local_images: true,
            image_advtab: true,
        }}
      />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, I am using the package linked & seeing content typed into the editor, I'm not sure how this content can be stored into a variable since, for regular textarea, I was handing this manually using an onChange event. But it seems no such prop exists on the TinyMCE component